# Brightness Temperature layered atmosphere

Tags: temperature, atmospheric-science, sensor, radiometry, radiative-transfer

I'm trying to figure out how to apply the radiative transfer model to calculate the brightness temperature Tb in microwave (Rayleigh–Jeans approximation) considering atmosphere and no scattering.
If I had a radiometer at the ground pointed upward perfectly vertical, in several papers I found that I can calculate Tb by:

[image]

I'm trying to better understand this formula in a simpler case. For example, I'm stuck in figure out how to modify this formula for a just two layer atmosphere (0/10km) and (10/20km) and assuming, let's say, a constant temperature for each atmosphere "layer".

My thought is to integrate from quote 0 to 20 km and dividing the integral in two parts in order to consider the constant temperature:

[image]

Any ideas?